# Dimming an AC-powered LED using Johnny-Five

Tags: arduino, esp8266, johnny-five, firmata

Is it possible to control Dimmable AC-powered LEDs using J5 on an ESP8266?

Working with the following:

- ESP8266 Microcontroller
- [RobotDyn AC Dimmer](https://robotdyn.com/ac-light-dimmer-module-1-channel-3-3v-5v-logic-ac-50-60hz-220v-110v.html)

**Question**: First up, Is this even possible using J5 over WiFi with an ESP8266?
I've read there are latency issues that cause flickering.

But assuming it is nonetheless possible...

Here's what I understand so far:

- Connect the Dimmer's PWM pin to a PWM-enabled ESP GPIO
- Connect Dimmer's Z-C (Zero Crossing) pin to another ESP GPIO set for Digital **Read**? or **Write**?

**Question**: On the J5 side, then what?
Been looking at [this StackExchange page](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/51852/arduino-code-for-pulse-skip-modulation-psm/51859#51859) for clues
Among the key commands in Arduino IDE is `attachInterrupt` (e.g. `attachInterrupt(0, zero_crosss_int, RISING)`)

**Question**: Is there an equivalent to `attachInterrupt()` in J5?

Comment: **Possible Clue**: 

In J5s node source (johnny-five/lib/pin.js) there's a prototype method commented out and with nothing in it:
`// Pin.prototype.isInterrupt = function() {
 }` suggesting perhaps this is something yet-to-be-developed.

Comment: **Another possible clue**: In StandardFirmataWiFi there's a function `readAndReportData` with the following comment in it: _some devices using an interrupt pin to signify new data available do not always require the register read so upon interrupt you call Wire.requestFrom()_.   Not sure what to do with that, but maybe someone with a better understanding of C/C+ will have an idea what's possible.